# Replace multiple new lines with one line in docx using VB .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, docx, uipath

I am working in UiPath Studio, this uses VB.NET . So i have a word document and i have to replace some texts.
I have for example a new line than some text than a new line… and sometimes i need to delete that “some text” and i am ending up having a word document with like 3 new lines between some texts, so i have multiple texts and multimple lines… so this is approximetly what it’s look like:

Some text1

Some text2

Some text3

Some text4

.......

And then if i replace Some text2 with String.Empty i am getting this:

Some text1

\n

\n

\n

Some text3

Some text4

.......

And i want to look like this:

Some text1

Some text3

Some text4

.......

I have multiple "Some text" so i need a general method to work.

Imagine that \n is not there, it's a new line. I just used it because if i write multiple new lines stackoverflow deletes them.

I tried everything, i tried like 20 diffrent methods and nothing worked, it's gotta be something that works.

I tried a lot of these things and other alternatives:

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(myText,"(\r\n|\r|\n)+", Environment.NewLine, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline)

But nothing worked.

Comment: You need to assign the Replace to a variable   string output = Replace(string, pattern).Value;

Comment: A docx file? Not a text file? You're going to have to open it with some openxml library and see how it's structured. They might not be newlinrs at all, but separate paragraph objects

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard you are a genius, it was actually \r instead of \n. I had to replace "\r\r\r" with "". So i did System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(myText,"\r\r\r","").

Answer (score 0):

**PagestringArray = PageString.Split({vbLf},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)**

this will remove \r, \a, \t etc

Send Hotkey "ctrl + a"
Send Hotkey "ctrl + c" 
"Copy Selected Text" or  "Get from clipboard" // fill the result field with the name of the variable that you are using to store the text for example: PageString

split 'PageString' to array of strings: 
Assign
PagestringArray = PageString.Split({vbLf},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

foreach item in PagestringArray

ResultString = ResultString + item.toString + "\n"

:) Save the string to a file